# How to properly clean an Android listener?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

Under Android we can declare some listener like in following example :

```
TErrorListener = class(TJavaLocal, JMediaPlayer_OnErrorListener)
  private
  public
  function onError(mp: JMediaPlayer; what: Integer; extra: Integer): Boolean; cdecl;
end;    

TmyObject = class
private
  FMediaPlayer: jmediaplayer;
  FOnErrorListener: TErrorListener;
end;
```

and then we can activate the `OnErrorListener` like this :

```
FMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(FOnErrorListener);
```

However, **deactivation** of such `OnErrorListener` is problematic.

In Delphi for Android UI thread and main thread are different threads and `onError` will be called in context of Android UI thread because of this function in underlying Java framework:

```
  //   Looper looper;
  //   if ((looper = Looper.myLooper()) != null) {
  //     mEventHandler = new EventHandler(this, looper);
  //   } else if ((looper = Looper.getMainLooper()) != null) {
  //     mEventHandler = new EventHandler(this, looper);
  //   } else {
  //     mEventHandler = null;
  //   }
```

Setting `FMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(nil);` in the main thread can cause problems because it's different from the UI thread that might be doing some work on internal variable `mOnErrorListener`.

I tried to synchronize deactivation with following code:

```
  CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing(
    procedure
    begin
      FMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(nil);
    end);
```

However, sometimes application crashes at that point and I don't know why. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you noted `CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing` has two overloads:

```
TMethodCallback = procedure of object;
TCallBack = reference to procedure;

procedure CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing(AMethod: TMethodCallback); overload;
procedure CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing(AMethod: TCallBack); overload;
```

---

In first one callback is regular method that does not have any special handling involved. After it executes your code continues to function in regular manner.

Using

```
CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing(aProcedureOfObject);
```

works because there is no hidden capturing behind the scenes.

---

In second one callback is anonymous method that comes with special feature - strong capturing of any variables used in method body. In case of

```
CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing(procedure
begin
  FmyObject.dosomething
end);
```

it will capture `FmyObject` variable.

That is first step in calling `CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing` with anonymous method callback. Next thing what happens is that Java runnable object is created

```
Runnable := TRunnable.Create(AMethod);
ActiveJavaRunnables.Add(Runnable);
Runnable.Start;
```

Above code stores your anonymous method (`AMethod`) in `TRunnable` `FCallback` field creating strong reference to your anonymous method as well as any variables that method captured.

And now it comes the real catch. `Runnable` object is not automatically cleared when your code executes - it is stored in `ActiveJavaRunnables` list and that list is cleared periodically in non-deterministic fashion - in sense that you don't know when it will be cleared and when it will actually release that `Runnable` and stored `FCallback` along with everything captured along the way.

If you want to use anonymous methods you have to create temporary weak reference to any object you use inside anonymous method body and use that weak reference instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found how I can avoid sporadic application crashes:

Never call

```
CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing(procedure
begin
  FmyObject.dosomething
end);
```

use following instead

```
CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing(aProcedureOfObject);
```

Why ?

Because the first variant will keep strong reference (without increasing the refcount - I don't know why) to `FmyObject`, and will later, after you already released `FmyObject`, try release it again resulting in exception.